# how to build a SOAP api in php

Tags: php, soapui, nusoap

I'm new to SOAP, still learning the syntax. I work in Php.
I have to build a SOAP application in Php. Searched everywhere for tutorials,examples..If someone know a good way of learning it, please help me.

Comment: http://bit.ly/NBlitQ => [this](http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/), [this](http://devzone.zend.com/25/php-soap-extension/) and [this](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Using-SOAP-with-PHP/)

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the Zend Soap Framework is very easy to use, more so than NuSoap or the native PHP functionality for SOAP.

There are other posts on StackOverflow on this subject:

- [How to generate a wsdl using zend soap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680651/how-to-generate-a-wsdl-using-zend-soap)

You can find out more about Zend Soap here:

- http://bogdan-albei.blogspot.com/2009/05/quickstart-web-services-with-soap-and.html
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.html

Comment: I work on NuSphere..if Zend Soap is more comfortable, i l try it..thank u Debock for the suggestion

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact, I'm using PhpEd as well and I've just recently switched from Nusoap to Zend Soap. Declaration of complex types is much faster with Zend. Hope this'll get you on the right track !!